# Binary protocol throw socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, binary

I am building c++ server that get the data from the client in Binary protocol. the protocol look like that:

Message code: 1 BYTE | Data length: 4 BYTES | Data: X BYTE

so i need to send information from the client that matching this protocol. so lets say that i want to send this data from the client:

Message code: 100
Data length: 4
Data: nice

How can i send in throw the socket? i mean the data length require only 1 byte, but in the protocol i want in to be 4 bytes permanently. so how can i complete the other 3 bytes? and how can i send data throw the socket that is not string?

this is my code so far:

```
import socket
PORT, IP = 5280, '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_ADDRESS = (IP, PORT)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS)

code = 100
length = 14
data = "nice"

sock.sendall(code)
sock.sendall(length)
sock.sendall(data.encode("ASCII"))

print "Server said:", sock.recv(1024) # Server response
sock.close()
```

I don't have a clue how to do it as i want... and how convert everything to binary. little fixes in my code will help, thank.

Comment: Use the `struct` module from the Python standard library, it does exactly what you're asking

Comment: But how can i pack only 1 byte? when i do: struct.pack('c', 100) i get an error. and if i want to pack unknown number of bytes? the documentation says i can pack only int, sort, char or long types, that their number of bytes is permanently.

Comment: Are you using Python 3 ? If you want to pack a single byte of value `100`, you could use `struct.pack("c", bytes([100]))`.

Comment: As for your second question, you'll always know the number of bytes you want to pack, since you know what data you're sending.

Comment: i am using python 2.7.. so how can i pack a char that is number?

Comment: `struct.pack("c", chr(100))`

Comment: thank!! i already swiped to python 3 but still

Comment: Though it accomplishes the same thing, it is more natural to use `struct.pack("b", 100)` if you have a number to start with. (Likewise, for the length, you will want `struct.pack("I", len(data))` [capital i] for an unsigned 4-byte integer.)

Comment: Yes, it's better indeed. I just assumed he wanted to keep the `c` in his format string without thinking further.